# nopcommerce password recovery not working properly

Tags: email, nopcommerce

Password recovery is not working on the server after deployment. It is working fine on the localhost. I checked password recovery template and it is showing active. I am getting all the other mails after deployment such as order confirmation and welcome mails but there is some problem in password recovery. If I check the message queue it is showing sent but we are not receiving it. I tried to change the message template and if I keep only the text instead of any URL's than it is working fine but when I add passwords recovery URL we are not getting mails. If URL is a problem than how my other mails are working. I haven't made any changes in the core files. I checked on the nopcommerce forum but there are no one facing this issue.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that the mail has not been sent to spam folder? :)

Comment: Yes I checked mail is not in spam folder.

Comment: What e-mail provider are you using? Could it be that they block the e-mail on SMTP level? :)

Comment: I am using gmail same email id is used on the local host as well also as I mentioned i am getting other mails from the same provider and also if I change the password recovery html to plain text (test) than i am receiving the mail but when i change it to default than i don't receive from the server.